# How to automate login into script.google.com using clasp?

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

I am trying to automate automatic login into script.google.com using clasp. Using below clasp command. However, it takes user to UI for entering credentials and further authentication before downloading ".clasprc" file.

`clasp login`

Is there a way to automate this login using a config file (storing the credentials) to eliminate the UI part?

Comment: Probably you can get an idea for your tooling by reviewing https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/tests/README.md#clasp-login

Answer (score 0):

You can login using `clasp login --no-localhost` once and you'll be permanently logged in from there for that computer.

---

Another option is the following:

Once you login on one computer, you can re-use your `~/.clasprc.json` (by copying it) to essentially login to another computer.